# Maven Java not warning about nonexhaustive switch

Tags: java, maven, switch-statement, compiler-warnings

If you switch on an enum, and neither cover all cases nor provide a default, it is useful to get a compiler warning. Other answers on this site have suggested that javac should provide such a warning.

I'm using Maven, and have added the following to pom.xml in an attempt to enable all warnings:

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>
          <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

But the compiler is still silent about nonexhaustive switch statements in my code. Is there some other flag I can set, to enable such warnings?

Comment: Why not have a SonarLint/Qube integration, in maven.

Comment: It's worth mentioning the Java and Maven versions you're using and sample code of course if good to be a part of the question to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know about such warnings because of:

- external settings, [like the IDE Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16797618/6309)
  (`Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings/Enum type constant not covered on switch`)
- external linter, like a [custom rule in SonarQube/SonarLint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50274321/6309)
- external tools like [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), and the [`SF_SWITCH_NO_DEFAULT` bug description](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SF_SWITCH_NO_DEFAULT)
- external projects, like [`tmtron/enum-mapper`](https://github.com/tmtron/enum-mapper)

The latter should be of interest:

> An annotation processor will make sure that you get a compile-time error.
>   The project also includes a partial enum-mapper class which you may want to use instead of a switch statement.

The project is [available in Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.tmtron.enums), so you could add it to your dependencies.

The point remains:

A [`javac` non-standard option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#nonstandard) like `-Xlint` might not be enough, alone, to catch that partial switch enum usecase.
It would only detects Fall-through cases: cases in a `switch` block, other than the last case in the block, **whose code does not include a break statement**, allowing code execution to "fall through" from that case to the **next case**.